# Android Buttons are overlapping while run

Tags: button, overlapping

I'm trying to create an Android App to control an RC-Car.
I'm just at the beginning and my App has only two Buttons. I'm using Android Studio and in my layout the two Buttons are among each other. But when I run the App only the top Button is shown. I tried many different things and I couldn't find a solution or why it is like that.

Here's my Layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="e.monaw.rc_car_v1.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOnOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btSpeed"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btSpeed"
    android:text="On/Off"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSpeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Speed"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope you can help me fix this problem! As how it is now I can't test it and I can't go on working on my App.

Comment: you should read a bit about how `ConstraintLayout` works

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! I'm new to Android Studio and didn't know that there were so many different layouts.